# Is K is a function?

Tags: functions, core-language, variable-definitions, implementation-details

Some of the capitalized single letters are functions. Starting a fresh kernel and typing in the 24 capital letters, the following letters turn black since they are special functions,

- `C` - an anonymous constant
- `D` - derivative
- `E` - natural number $e$
- `I` - imaginary unit
- `K` - ???
- `N` - numerical value
- `O` - order

The weird thing is that `K` turns black, but it has no documentation and can be used as a variable without much issue. I only realized this because I was using `K` as a constant and it caused a `ParallelTable` to hang (whereas the corresponding `Table` has no issues), but I have not yet been able to produce a MWE.

So, is `K` a function? Is it being reserved for something? Is it known that it can potentially cause problems? Or is this a bug?

Comment: `? K` gives me answer. Is it a satisfactory one to you? If not, why not?

Comment: It's relatively easy to remember which symbols not to use. Either don't use capital letters, or don't use the ones that spell `ONE` and a word that is a reference to the male anatomy; hint it starts with a `D` and ends with a `K`

Comment: @MichaelE2 it gives an answer, but it's not documented, right? So I guess the situation is not very satisfactory.

Comment: @MichaelE2 This isn't the end: `DSolve[y'[x] == f[x], y, x]` Of course one may argue that integral is an infinite sum.

Comment: @xzczd `? K` gives a sufficient hint, though (imo). And @ bmf, `K::usage` is a form of documentation, and usage messages are themselves documented (in the doc pages for `Information`, `MessageName`, etc. and related tutorials, for instance, in the aptly named [Documentation Constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#4287)).

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for sharing your thought and providing feedback. I guess what I meant by saying undocumented is the following: see the difference for [`K`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOj6r.png) and for [`C`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjaMr.png). I should have been more explicit. Please don't delete your comment. I think it makes sense to have this comment section here. Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
?? K
```

> [image: k]

To get them all, I guess the following works

```
Select[Names["System`*"], 
 StringLength[#] == 1 && 
   UpperCaseQ[#] && ! 
    StringMatchQ[ToString[FullForm[#]], "*Formal*"] &]
```

> [image: all]

As far as I can tell, `K` is the only undocumented capitalized built-in symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of `?` or `??`

Comment: @Kai glad I was able to help!

Comment: +1 and nice code too. Didn't get your comment on  male anatomy until I saw this!

Comment: @hana I guess I should have included it as part of the answer :) Many thanks for the kind words

Comment: Slightly shorter using Select[Names["System`"~~_] to get 1 letter symbols.

Comment: @Somos thanks for pointing this. Very elegant, indeed!!!

Comment: Side note: Unlike other capitalized built-in symbol, `K` is not `Protected`. And, it's strange that, the message is already in _v3_, but I cannot find an example that actually use it therein!: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q317q.png

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for the comment and totally agree with you. This K-situation is strange indeed

Comment: ONE DICK........