# Solve symbolic ODE with symbolic initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I have the following ODE

c + (p + r) y[p] == p (u + (-1 + p) y'[p])

where car and u are parameters of the problem. I want to solve the ODE using a symbolic initial condition y(0)=x for some x, or also to impose an initial condition of the form y(z)=x where both x and y are symbols. For both these issues I tried to do DSolve, getting the solution with the constant C[1] and then using Solve[y(0)==x, c[1]] but I get error. I guess I should define a function y which maps p and c[1] and use that in Solve. Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Comment: There are some mistakes in the code. If you try the o.d.e without a boundary condition you get an answer `sol = DSolveValue[{c + (p + r) y[p] == p (u + (-1 + p) y'[p])}, 
   y[p], {p, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify` and then taking the limit `Limit[sol, p -> 0]` you should be able to see something

Comment: Another comment: you should **NOT** be using `K` --- see [`this answer`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266402/is-k-is-a-function/266404#266404).

Comment: Your syntax is also wrong. You need `{...}` around the ode and the bc. Also you really do not need to say `{p,0,1}` as this is analytical solution. You are not using `NDSolve` here. Try this from clean system`ode = c + (p + r) y[p] == p (u + (-1 + p) y'[p]);
ic = y[0] == k;
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[p], p]`  which gives `{}` as solution.

Comment: Your IC does not give solution. If you do this `sol = DSolveValue[ode, y[p], p]` then `eq = k == Limit[sol, p -> 0] // InputForm` it will give `ConditionalExpression[k == ComplexInfinity, Element[c | u, Reals] && r > 1 && C[1] > 0]`  so it is not possible to solve the constant for the integration `C[1]` that is why Mathematica can't find solution. If you copied from this a book, make sure you copied the IC correctly.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I am totally new to mathematic and I need this for my research. I edited the question to make it more meaningful.