# Evaluate@ creates additional branch in plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following code to create a list of functions:

```
a1 = {\[Sqrt](3), 0};
a2 = {\[Sqrt](3/4), 3/2};

r1 = {0, 0, 0};
r2 = {\[Sqrt](3), 1 , 0};

b1 = 2*\[Pi]*{1/\[Sqrt](3), -1/3};
b2 = 2*\[Pi]*{0, 2/3};

\[CapitalGamma] = {0, 0};
M = (1/2)*b2;
K = (2/3)*b1 + (1/3)*b2;
Energie = Function[a, a . a] ;
EnergieFunc = Function[{\[Kappa]}, Function[ {a}, Energie[\ 
[Kappa] + a]]];
Offsets = {\[CapitalGamma], b1, b1 + b2, b2, -b1, -b1 - b2, - 
b2};
EnergieFunctions = Table[EnergieFunc[Offsets[[i]]], {i, 1, 7}];
```

I then create a piecewise function to give a path

```
BandPath =  Function[{t}, Piecewise[{{\[CapitalGamma] + (M - \[CapitalGamma])*4  t/3,t<=3/4},{M(K - M)*4  (t - 3/4)/7, 
 t < 3/4 + 7/4  && 
 t > 3/4}, {K + (\[CapitalGamma] - K)*(t - 3/4 - 7/4), 
 t > 10/4}}]]
```

When I know plot the function along the path (t, 0, 3.5), I get the following plot

Code:

```
Plot[EnergieFunctions[[1]][BandPath[t]], {t, 0, 3.5}]
```

Plot:
[image]

But if I enter an additional Evaluate@ in front, I get this plot:

Code:

```
Plot\[CapitalGamma]toK = Plot[Evaluate@EnergieFunctions[[1]][BandPath[t]], {t, 0, 1 + 10/4} ]
```

Plot:
[image]

This is not what I want, however, I would like to use the evaluate function for different reasons. Does anyone understand why this is?

I would really appreciate some help

Comment: We cannot reproduce your results unless you tell us the values for `{K, M, Γ}`

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: b1 = 2*\[Pi]*{1/\[Sqrt](3), -1/3};
b2 = 2*\[Pi]*{0, 2/3};

\[CapitalGamma] = {0, 0};
M = (1/2)*b2;
K = (2/3)*b1 + (1/3)*b2;

Comment: Don't put necessary info in a comment. Edit the question to include all necessary info.

Comment: In addition to the comments by @BobHanlon you are using both `K` and `κ`. I assume you only wanted to use one. You should **NOT** be using `K` as it is a built-in symbol.

Comment: No I wanted to use both. But I will try to use something else now, thanks for the comment

Comment: Oh yes and I edited the the question, thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by K is a built-in symbol. In my notebook, K is colored blue so I think I am allowed to use it or not?

Comment: I just saw the comments and by accident. If you want to notify a user that is not the author of the OP, please use @ then start typing said user's name so a notification will pop up. As for the [`K symbol`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266402/is-k-is-a-function/266404#266404) you can read in the link I provided.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

b1 = 2*π*{1/√(3), -1/3};
b2 = 2*π*{0, 2/3};
Γ = {0, 0};
M = (1/2)*b2;
k = (2/3)*b1 + (1/3)*b2;
```

Note that `K` is used internally to represent arbitrary functions and variables; this is similar to how `C` is used. In most cases there will be no conflict but it is better to avoid using `K` as a user-defined variable.

```
Energie = Function[{a}, a . a];
EnergieFunc = Function[{κ}, Function[{a}, Energie[κ + a]]];
Offsets = {Γ, b1, b1 + b2, b2, -b1, -b1 - b2, -b2};
```

Note the `EnergieFunctions` can be defined more simply by

```
EnergieFunctions = EnergieFunc /@ Offsets;

BandPath = 
  Function[{t}, 
   Piecewise[{{Γ + (M - Γ)*4 t/3, 
      t <= 3/4}, {M (k - M)*4 (t - 3/4)/7, 
      t < 3/4 + 7/4 && t > 3/4}, {k + (Γ - k)*(t - 3/4 - 7/4), 
      t > 10/4}}]];
```

The two functions being plotted are

```
funcs = EnergieFunctions[[1]][BandPath[t]] // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify
```

[image]

Instead of using `Evaluate` on the function, you can use the option `Evaluated -> True`

```
Plot[EnergieFunctions[[1]][BandPath[t]],
 {t, 0, 7/2},
 Exclusions -> {3/4, 5/2},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[EnergieFunctions[[1]][BandPath[t]]],
 {t, 0, 1 + 10/4},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Because of the way you have defined the functions, `Plot` cannot determine that there are two functions until the numerical values are assigned. The two functions are more readily seen by splitting the definitions

```
func1 = funcs /. {{x_, y_}, cond_} :> {x, cond}
```

[image]

```
func2 = funcs /. {{x_, y_}, cond_} :> {y, cond}
```

[image]

Then,

```
Plot[{func1, func2}, {t, 0, 7/2},
 Frame -> True,
 Exclusions -> {3/4, 5/2},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.3, .7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks! That is really helpful. But I still don't understand why it happens why I get 2 functions with evaluate and 1 without it. And I don't understand what PiecewiseExpand does that shows these 2 functions.

Comment: The `PiecewiseExpand` doesn't change the number of functions. Remove it and you will get the same first two plots. It is used to help simplify the expression for `funcs` and facilitate separating `funcs` into its two parts.

Comment: Okay, but if I don't do the Evaluate@ in front, then I don't get two values. Why is this? Because evaluate should also not change the number of the function, correct?              And I also wanted to say that I used Evaluated -> True instead of Evaluate, but it created the same two branches as Evaluate

Comment: It is difficult to anticipate how your unevaluated code will evaluate inside `Plot` because your functions are pure functions (even a nested pure function). `Function` as well as `Plot` have the attribute `HoldAll` and without some form of `Evaluate` (e.g., using `Evaluate`, the option `Evaluated -> True`, or defining and plotting `funcs`) it is difficult to know when the various holds will be released and the associated effect as each is released. Defining `funcs` shows you exactly how the evaluated code is interpreted. If that is not the desired interpretation, change your definitions.