# How to accelerate FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

**Original:**

I am running the following code to find the root of ***F*** , ***T*** and ***MM***, here is an example

```
L = 10; l = L*(3/10); DD = 1; mu = 1; sol = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{\[Phi]1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[\[Phi]1[s]] == 
    0, \[Phi]2''[s] - T*Sin[\[Phi]2[s]] == 0, \[Phi]1[0] == 
    0, \[Phi]2'[L] == MM, \[Phi]1[l] == \[Phi]2[l] == 
    ArcTan[1/mu]}, {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}, {s, 0, L}, {T, F, MM}]; 
m1[s_, T_, F_, MM_] := 
 Evaluate[Evaluate[\[Phi]1[T, F, MM] /. sol][s]]; 
m2[s_, T_, F_, MM_] := 
 Evaluate[Evaluate[\[Phi]2[T, F, MM] /. sol][s]]; 
dm1[s_, T_, F_, MM_] := Evaluate[D[m1[s, T, F, MM], s]]; 
dm2[s_, T_, F_, MM_] := Evaluate[D[m2[s, T, F, MM], s]]; 
BC1[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ, MM_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Cos[m1[s, T, F, MM]], {s, 0, l}] - DD; 
BC2[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ, MM_?NumericQ] := -dm1[l, T, F, MM] - 
  T*(NIntegrate[Sin[m2[s, T, F, MM]], {s, l, L}]) + MM; 
BC3[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ, MM_?NumericQ] := m2[L, T, F, MM]; sol2 =
  Monitor[
  FindRoot[{BC1[T, F, MM] == 0, BC2[T, F, MM] == 0, 
    BC3[T, F, MM] == 0}, {{T, 1}, {F, 1}, {MM, 1}}], {T, F, MM}]
```

I've noticed that it takes quite a long time to get a response, and there's no assurance of the solution's accuracy. It's worth noting that the parameter ***DD*** can range between 0.01 and 2, and this makes the code's performance decline further when ***DD*** is small.

I'm seeking advice on techniques that can improve the speed and accuracy of the FindRoot function. Thanks a lot!

**Update1:**

I have removed the variable ***MM*** because it seems unnecessary, and the boundary conditions have also been changed for simplicity.Here is my updated code:

```
  L = 10; l = L*(3/10); DD = 0.1; mu = 1;
         sol = 
             ParametricNDSolve[{ϕ1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 
                0, ϕ2''[s] - T*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, ϕ1[0] == 
                0, ϕ2'[L] == 0, ϕ1[l] == ϕ2[l] == 
                ArcTan[1/mu]}, {ϕ1, ϕ2}, {s, 0, L}, {T, F}]; 
            m1[s_, T_, F_] := 
             Evaluate[Evaluate[ϕ1[T, F] /. sol][s]]; 
            m2[s_, T_, F_] := 
             Evaluate[Evaluate[ϕ2[T, F] /. sol][s]]; 
            dm1[s_, T_, F_] := Evaluate[D[m1[s, T, F], s]]; 
            dm2[s_, T_, F_] := Evaluate[D[m2[s, T, F], s]]; 
            BC1[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] := 
             NIntegrate[Cos[m1[s, T, F]], {s, 0, l}] - DD; 
            BC2[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] := -dm1[l, T, F] + dm2[l, T, F]; 
           sol2 =
              Monitor[
              FindRoot[{BC1[T, F] == 0, BC2[T, F] == 0}, {{T, 1}, {F, 1}}], {T, F}]
```

Moreover, define a Piecewise function which is the conbination of ϕ1 and ϕ2,

```
fin[s_] := Piecewise[{{ϕ1[s], 0 <= s < l}, {ϕ2[s], l <= s <= L}}];
```

Since for different initial values used in **Findroot**, we can get different ϕ1 and ϕ2. However, the shape of fin[s] shown in the following figure is actually my goal.
[image]

**Update2:**

I especially need the results in condition of smaller ***DD*** and ***l***. Such as

```
l = L*(2/100); DD = 0.1;
```

or even at a more extreme one

```
l = L*(2/1000); DD = 0.01;
```

I’m curious about what causes such difficulty in solving these equations at this condition in function `FindRoot` and `NDSolve`. Are there any techniques that can help improve this situation?

Comment: Are you sure that your problem has single solution? It seems that you don't use  ``$\]Phi\1$` and `\[Phi]2` except for computing `\[Phi]1'` and `\[Phi]2'`. Why don't you instruct `ParametricNDSolve` to return `\[Phi]1'` and `\[Phi]2'` rather then `\[Phi]1` and `\[Phi]2` ?``

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov. I appreciate your comment. I am new to Mathematica and I am not sure which method is the best. I would be grateful for any method that can solve this system of equations. I understand that the value of `\[Phi]1` and `\[Phi]2` is not unique, it will depend on the initial value of the solution and converge to different results.

Comment: Hi. I am using similar shooting method to solve boundary-value problem. First of all, I would recommend explicitly restrict the range of expected values of free parameters in ParamentricNDSolve and instruct it to return only those functions which you need. Here is my case: 
`ParametricNDSolveValue[
 {ode$[k, z, p, {q, Mm, Rm}, \[CapitalLambda]] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 
   1, \[Phi]'[0] == 0}
 , {\[Phi]'[zR$], \[Phi][zR$]}
 , {z, 0, (1 + 0* 10^-7) zR$}
 , {{p, 0, pmx}, {\[CapitalLambda], 1, 500}}
 (*,Method->{"StiffnessSwitching"}
 ,Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}*)`
 ]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `g = T - F`, the equations for ϕ1 and ϕ2 can be decoupled and solved sequentially.  **Consider ϕ1.**

```
sL = 10; sm = sL*(3/10); dd = 1; mu = 1;
```

and

```
{ϕ1''[s] - g*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 0, ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ1[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu]};
```

(I have changed the names of some parameters to avoid using capital letters and for clarity.)

There remains the BC1 boundary condition, which requires that the integral of `Cos[ϕ1[s]]`over `{s, 0, sm}` be equal to `dd`.  Introduce the new variable `d'[s] = Cos[ϕ1[s]]`.  Then this boundary condition becomes simply `d[sm] - d[0] == dd`.

Finally, determining the eigenvalue `g` can be accomplished using the procedure described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691).  Combining all these yields

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{ϕ1''[s] - g[s]*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 0, g'[s] == 0, 
    d'[s] == Cos[ϕ1[s]], ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ1[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
    d[0] == 0, d[sm] == dd}, {ϕ1[s], ϕ1'[s], g[sm]}, {s, 0, sL}];

sol1[[3]
(* -1.13517 *)
NIntegrate[Cos[sol1[[1]]], {s, 0, sm}]
(* 1. *)
```

where the first value is `g` and the second verifies that the integral of `Cos[ϕ1[s]]` is indeed `dd`.  And,

```
Plot[Evaluate@sol1[[;; 2]], {s, 0, sL}, AxesLabel -> {s, "ϕ1,ϕ1'"},
    PlotLabels -> Placed[{"ϕ1", "ϕ1'"}, {{Scaled[1], Before}}], 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Next, **consider ϕ2.**

```
{ϕ2''[s] - t*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, ϕ2[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu, ϕ2'[sL] == mm];
```

together with `BC2` and `BC3`.  The integral in `BC2` is solved analytically by integrating the `ϕ2` ODE once to obtain `ϕ2[sL] - ϕ2[sm]`, obviating the need to introduce an auxiliary variable similar `d` for `ϕ1`.  The two remaining terms in this boundary condition are given by `ϕ2'[sL]` (`mm` from the third equation above) and `ϕ1'[sm]`.  Combined, `ϕ2'[sm] == (sol1[[2]] /. s -> sm)`.  In other words, `ϕ1` and `ϕ2` are tangent at `sm`.  Finally, `BC3` is equivalent to `ϕ2[sL] == 0`.  In total,

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{ϕ2''[s] - t[s]*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, t'[s] == 0, 
    ϕ2'[sm] == (sol1[[2]] /. s -> sm), ϕ2[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu],
    ϕ2[sL] == 0}, {ϕ2[s], ϕ2'[s], t[sm]}, {s, 0, sL}, 
    InitialSeeding -> t[sL] == -1/2];

sol2[[3]]
(* -0.597091 *)
```

is the value of the eigenvalue `t` here.  Note that many values of `t` satisfy the `ϕ2` system.  I chose `InitialSeeding -> t[sL] == -1` to bias the calculation toward a solution resembling `ϕ1` above.

```
Plot[Evaluate@sol2[[;; 2]], {s, 0, sL}, AxesLabel -> {s, "ϕ2,ϕ2'"},
    PlotLabels -> Placed[{"ϕ2", "ϕ2'"}, {{Scaled[1], Before}}],
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Overlay `ϕ1` and `ϕ2` for completeness.  As expected, the curves are tangent at `sm`.

```
Plot[{sol1[[1]], sol2[[1]]}, {s, 0, sL}, AxesLabel -> {s, "ϕ1,ϕ2"},
    PlotLabels -> Placed[{"ϕ1", "ϕ2"}, {{Scaled[1], Before}}],
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Incidentally, the solution obtained by Alex Trounev can be obtained by using `InitialSeeding -> t[sL] == -1/2`.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Thank you very much for your help! However, I encountered some difficulties with your method when the parameter DD is small. For example, when DD=0.1, Mathematica does not find the accurate solution of T and ϕ2. Do you have any suggestions on how to overcome this inaccuracy? By the way, I have eliminated the variable MM to make the question clearer.

Comment: With my code above, I obtained a result for `dd =1/10` without difficulty.  It looks like the result in my answer, but with `ϕ1` and `ϕ2` overlapping more closely.  I see that you have added a curve to your question.  How did you obtain this result, and what are the associated values of your input parameters and of `F` and `T`?.

Comment: Thanks again! To get the curve I added to the question, I choose the initial parameters：sL = 10; sm = sL*(2/10); dd = 1; mu = 1. For sol1, I have added InitialSeeding -> {\[Phi]1'[0] == 2}, thus getting g[sm]=-2.08538. For sol2, here is my following code: sol2 = NDSolveValue[{\[Phi]2''[s] - t[s]*Sin[\[Phi]2[s]] == 0, t'[s] == 0, \[Phi]2'[sm] == (Evaluate[sol1[[2]]][s] /. s -> sm), \[Phi]2[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu], \[Phi]2'[sL] == 0}, {\[Phi]2, \[Phi]2', t[sm]}, {s, sm, sL}, InitialSeeding -> {\[Phi]2[sL] == 0}]. The boundary conditions have been changed since I have deleted the variable MM.

Comment: You also seem to have replaced `ϕ2[sL] == 0` (the equivalent of `BC3 == 0`) by `ϕ2'[sL] == 0`.

Comment: I agree with the comment below by @AlexTrounev that you should not change a question that already has received answers.  If you have a new question, post it as such.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. Now I have restored the question and posted an updated one.

Answer (score 3):

We can add `BC1,BC2,BC3` to the system of equations and solve it as DAE system. Unfortunately `NDSolve` can't solve this type DAE. Therefore we use our favorable the Euler wavelets collocation method described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278398/unstable-boundary-values-using-ndsolve/278407#278407), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280489/replacing-custom-built-code-to-solve-helfrich-model-with-ndsolve/280608#280608), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275496/highly-coupled-nonlinear-second-order-differential-equations/275587#275587). For this we map system on $0\le s\le1$ using scale L, we have

```
L = 10; l = (3/
   10); DD = 1; mu = 1; {ϕ1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 
  0, ϕ2''[s] - T*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, f1'[s] == Cos[ϕ1[s]],
  f2'[s] == Sin[ϕ2[s]], ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ2'[L] == 
  MM, ϕ1[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], ϕ2[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
 f1[0] == 0, 
 f2[0] == 0}; eqs = {p1''[s]/L^2 - (T - F)*Sin[p1[s]] == 0, 
  p2''[s]/L^2 - T*Sin[p2[s]] == 0, f1'[s]/L == Cos[p1[s]], 
  f2'[s]/L == Sin[p2[s]]}; bc = {p1[0] == 0, p2'[1]/L == MM, 
  p1[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], p2[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], f1[0] == 0, 
  f2[0] == 0, p2[1] == 0, MM - p1'[l]/L - T (f2[1] - f2[l]) == 0, 
  f1[l] - DD == 0}; rule = {p1'' -> ddp1, p1' -> dp1, p2'' -> ddp2, 
  p2' -> dp2, f1' -> df1, f2' -> df2};
eqs1 = eqs /. rule; bc1 = bc /. rule;
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 6; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;

P1 = Array[pp1, {nn}]; P2 = Array[pp2, {nn}]; F1 = 
 Array[ff1, {nn}]; F2 = Array[ff2, {nn}];
ddp1[s_] := P1 . Psi[s]; dp1[s_] := P1 . int1[s] + a0; 
p1[s_] := P1 . int2[s] + a0 s + a1;
ddp2[s_] := P2 . Psi[s]; dp2[s_] := P2 . int1[s] + b0; 
p2[s_] := P2 . int2[s] + b0 s + b1;
df1[s_] := F1 . Psi[s]; f1[s_] := F1 . int1[s] + c0; 
df2[s_] := F2 . Psi[s]; f2[s_] := F2 . int1[s] + d0;
eqn = Table[eqs1, {s, ycol}];
eqsAll = Join[Flatten[eqn], bc];
var = Join[{T, F, MM, a0, a1, b0, b1, c0, d0}, P1, P2, F1, F2];
```

Numerical solution (note that we use `FindRoot` one time only!)

```
sol1 = FindRoot[eqsAll, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}]];
```

Visualization

```
plot1= Plot[Evaluate[{p1[s/L], p2[s/L]} /. sol1], {s, 0, L}, 
     PlotLegends -> {ϕ1, ϕ2}]
```

[image: Figure1]

Now we can solve this problem with NDSolve using parameters

```
rule1 = Take[sol1, 3]

(*Out[]= {T -> -0.597091, F -> 0.53808, MM -> 1.44889}*)
L = 10; l = 
 L*(3/10); DD = 1; mu = 1; 
solq = NDSolveValue[{ϕ1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 
     0, ϕ2''[s] - T*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, 
    f1'[s] == Cos[ϕ1[s]], 
    f2'[s] == Sin[ϕ2[s]], ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ2'[L] == 
     MM, ϕ2[L] == 0, f1[0] == 0, f2[0] == 0, f1[l] == DD} /. 
   rule1, {ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ1', ϕ2', f1, f2}, {s, 0, L}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}];
```

Visualization together with `plot1`

```
Show[plot1, Plot[Table[solq[[i]][s], {i, 2}] // Evaluate, {s, 0, L}, 
  PlotLegends -> {ϕ1, ϕ2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

As we can see two solutions consider well. Finally note, that we update boundary conditions using `BC1,BC3` instead of `ϕ1[l] == ϕ2[l] ==     ArcTan[1/mu]` since `NDSolve` can't handle boundary conditions in the intermediate point `s=l` with high accuracy. We can check that `solq` satisfiers these equations with error of

```
{solq[[1]][l] - ArcTan[1/mu], solq[[2]][l] - ArcTan[1/mu]}

(*Out[]= {1.06451*10^-8, -2.84661*10^-7}*)
```

**Update 1.** Solution for updated problem

```
L = 10; l = (3/10); DD = 1; mu = 1; {ϕ1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 
  0, ϕ2''[s] - T*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, f1'[s] == Cos[ϕ1[s]],
  f2'[s] == Sin[ϕ2[s]], ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ2'[L] == 
  MM, ϕ1[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], ϕ2[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
 f1[0] == 0, 
 f2[0] == 0}; eqs = {p1''[s]/L^2 - (T - F)*Sin[p1[s]] == 0, 
  p2''[s]/L^2 - T*Sin[p2[s]] == 0, 
  f1'[s]/L == Cos[p1[s]]}; bc = {p1[0] == 0, p1[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
  p2[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], f1[0] == 0, p2[1] == 0, 
  p2'[l]/L - p1'[l]/L == 0, f1[l] - DD == 0}; rule = {p1'' -> ddp1, 
  p1' -> dp1, p2'' -> ddp2, p2' -> dp2, f1' -> df1};
eqs1 = eqs /. rule; bc1 = bc /. rule;
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 6; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;

P1 = Array[pp1, {nn}]; P2 = Array[pp2, {nn}]; F1 = Array[ff1, {nn}];
ddp1[s_] := P1 . Psi[s]; dp1[s_] := P1 . int1[s] + a0;
p1[s_] := P1 . int2[s] + a0 s + a1;
ddp2[s_] := P2 . Psi[s]; dp2[s_] := P2 . int1[s] + b0;
p2[s_] := P2 . int2[s] + b0 s + b1;
df1[s_] := F1 . Psi[s]; f1[s_] := F1 . int1[s] + c0;
eqn = Table[eqs1, {s, ycol}];
eqsAll = Join[Flatten[eqn], bc];
sol2 = FindRoot[eqsAll, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}]];

plot2 = Plot[Evaluate[{p1[s/L], p2[s/L]} /. sol2], {s, 0, L}, 
  PlotLegends -> {ϕ1, ϕ2}, PlotRange -> All]

fin[s_] := 
  Piecewise[{{p1[s/L] /. sol2, 0 <= s < l L}, {p2[s/L] /. sol2, 
     l L <= s <= L}}];

Plot[Evaluate[fin[s]], {s, 0, L}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

**Update 2** In the code above we put `l = (2/10); DD = 1/10;`, results shown below
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: @ Alex Trounev. Thanks a lot for your help! I believe your method could solve my problem completely. However, I'm still learning your code since I am new to the Euler wavelets collocation method, and I would like to know how to adjust the initial seeds to get different ϕ1 and ϕ2 through your method.  By the way, I have removed the variable MM to simplify the question.

Comment: @Mikoto Did you offer a new problem instead of old one? It seems to be against rule of this forum as I understand. Normally we use update for the old question with new  thoughts.

Comment: @ Alex Trounev.I tried to make the problem clearer by simplifying it instead of offering a new one. I removed the variable MM because it seemed unnecessary and it made the problem more difficult. I also shared some of the results I am aiming for, but I don’t know how to pick the initial seeds to get them. I don't know whether it will against the rules this forum since I am new to here. Please forgive me if this modification makes you confused.

Comment: @Mikoto It is not confusing me, it is not clear for readers who will try to understand to which task I gave my solution. :)

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. Now I have restored the question and posted an updated one, which won't confuse any readers.

Comment: @Mikoto  I see that you also changed the parameters $l, DD$. Do you need solution for `l = L*(2/100); DD = 0.1`?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a solution to l = L*(2/100); DD = 0.1. I tried using FindRoot with different initial seeds in your method, but it was very slow and not accurate enough.I would like to know whether there exists a way to make this method more efficient and reliable, especially for more extreme cases like l = L*(2/1000); DD = 0.01. I’m sorry if my previous updates made this question more confusing for readers. I’m still learning about this problem and encountering many unexpected errors. I’ll try to add more details to the question text to make it clearer.

Comment: @Mikoto The bottleneck of this problem is `FindRoot`, but we can force it using `Do` loop with parameter `l`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I’m still a bit confused about what you mean. Could you please provide me with an example of how to write such a `Do` loop? I’m having trouble solving this system of equations using your method at small `l`.

Comment: @Mikoto Actually this question has an answer. Now you have a new problem with small $l, DD$. Could you start a new topic with explanation of your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, now I have posted a new one in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287824/how-to-improve-the-accuracy-of-findroot-or-ndsolvevalue-at-extreme-conditions-in, i would like to invite you to share your unique perspectives to us. Thanks again!