# How to improve the accuracy of FindRoot or NDSolveValue at extreme conditions in my equation system?

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

**This is a follow up question to my earlier one.** I have posted a question related to a DAE system. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287397/how-to-accelerate-findroot/287450?noredirect=1#comment716521_287450) is my earlier question and the equation system **now** I am asking for an answer is

```
 L = 10; l = L*(3/1000); DD = 0.01; mu = 1;
     sol = 
         ParametricNDSolve[{ϕ1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 
            0, ϕ2''[s] - T*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, ϕ1[0] == 
            0, ϕ2'[L] == 0, ϕ1[l] == ϕ2[l] == 
            ArcTan[1/mu]}, {ϕ1, ϕ2}, {s, 0, L}, {T, F}]; 
        m1[s_, T_, F_] := 
         Evaluate[Evaluate[ϕ1[T, F] /. sol][s]]; 
        m2[s_, T_, F_] := 
         Evaluate[Evaluate[ϕ2[T, F] /. sol][s]]; 
        dm1[s_, T_, F_] := Evaluate[D[m1[s, T, F], s]]; 
        dm2[s_, T_, F_] := Evaluate[D[m2[s, T, F], s]]; 
        BC1[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] := 
         NIntegrate[Cos[m1[s, T, F]], {s, 0, l}] - DD; 
        BC2[T_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] := -dm1[l, T, F] + dm2[l, T, F]; 
       sol2 =
          Monitor[
          FindRoot[{BC1[T, F] == 0, BC2[T, F] == 0}, {{T, 1}, {F, 1}}], {T, F}];
```

then define a piecewise function which is the conbination of `ϕ1` and `ϕ2`,

```
fin[s_] := Piecewise[{{ϕ1[s], 0 <= s < l}, {ϕ2[s], l <= s <= L}}];
```

Since for different initial values used in Findroot, we can get different `ϕ1` and `ϕ2`. However, the shape of `fin[s]` shown in the following figure is actually my goal.

[image]

Actually in my earlier question I have received two answers from [@AlexTrounev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287450/93487) and [@bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287440/93487). However, the parameters there are set to `l = L*(3/10); DD = 1;` . Now in this one I especially need the results in condition of smaller ***DD*** and ***l***. I have found there codes work not very well at small ***DD*** and ***l***. It seems there exists a bottleneck in function `FindRoot` and `NDSolveValue` at extreme conditions, for example, in this question they are set to

```
l = L*(3/1000); DD = 0.01;
```

I’m curious about what causes such difficulty in solving these equations at this condition in function `FindRoot` and `NDSolveValue`. Are there any techniques that can help improve this situation?

For ease of reading, here I paste the answer I have received in my eariler question:

***Answer from AlexTrounev:***

```
L = 10; l = (3/10); DD = 1; mu = 1; {ϕ1''[s] - (T - F)*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 
  0, ϕ2''[s] - T*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, f1'[s] == Cos[ϕ1[s]],
  f2'[s] == Sin[ϕ2[s]], ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ2'[L] == 
  MM, ϕ1[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], ϕ2[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
 f1[0] == 0, 
 f2[0] == 0}; eqs = {p1''[s]/L^2 - (T - F)*Sin[p1[s]] == 0, 
  p2''[s]/L^2 - T*Sin[p2[s]] == 0, 
  f1'[s]/L == Cos[p1[s]]}; bc = {p1[0] == 0, p1[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
  p2[l] == ArcTan[1/mu], f1[0] == 0, p2[1] == 0, 
  p2'[l]/L - p1'[l]/L == 0, f1[l] - DD == 0}; rule = {p1'' -> ddp1, 
  p1' -> dp1, p2'' -> ddp2, p2' -> dp2, f1' -> df1};
eqs1 = eqs /. rule; bc1 = bc /. rule;
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 6; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;

P1 = Array[pp1, {nn}]; P2 = Array[pp2, {nn}]; F1 = Array[ff1, {nn}];
ddp1[s_] := P1 . Psi[s]; dp1[s_] := P1 . int1[s] + a0;
p1[s_] := P1 . int2[s] + a0 s + a1;
ddp2[s_] := P2 . Psi[s]; dp2[s_] := P2 . int1[s] + b0;
p2[s_] := P2 . int2[s] + b0 s + b1;
df1[s_] := F1 . Psi[s]; f1[s_] := F1 . int1[s] + c0;
eqn = Table[eqs1, {s, ycol}];
eqsAll = Join[Flatten[eqn], bc];
var = Join[{T, F, MM, a0, a1, b0, b1, c0, d0}, P1, P2, F1, F2];  
    sol2 = FindRoot[eqsAll, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}]];

plot2 = Plot[Evaluate[{p1[s/L], p2[s/L]} /. sol2], {s, 0, L}, 
  PlotLegends -> {ϕ1, ϕ2}, PlotRange -> All]

fin[s_] := 
  Piecewise[{{p1[s/L] /. sol2, 0 <= s < l L}, {p2[s/L] /. sol2, 
     l L <= s <= L}}];

Plot[Evaluate[fin[s]], {s, 0, L}]
```

***Answer from bbgodfrey:***

```
sL = 10; sm = sL*(3/10); dd = 1; mu = 1;
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{ϕ1''[s] - g[s]*Sin[ϕ1[s]] == 0, g'[s] == 0, 
    d'[s] == Cos[ϕ1[s]], ϕ1[0] == 0, ϕ1[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu], 
    d[0] == 0, d[sm] == dd}, {ϕ1[s], ϕ1'[s], g[sm]}, {s, 0, sL}];

sol1[[3]
(* -1.13517 *)
NIntegrate[Cos[sol1[[1]]], {s, 0, sm}]
(* 1. *)
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{ϕ2''[s] - t[s]*Sin[ϕ2[s]] == 0, t'[s] == 0, 
    ϕ2'[sm] == (sol1[[2]] /. s -> sm), ϕ2[sm] == ArcTan[1/mu],
    ϕ2[sL] == 0}, {ϕ2[s], ϕ2'[s], t[sm]}, {s, 0, sL}, 
    InitialSeeding -> t[sL] == -1/2];

sol2[[3]]
(* -0.597091 *)
```

Comment: This problem has no unique solution. But we can define general solution to this problem, for instance, `ϕ1[s_] = 2 JacobiAmplitude[k1 Sqrt[F - T] s, k1^-2]`, and `ϕ2[s_] = Pi + 2 JacobiAmplitude[(s k2 Sqrt[T] + c), k2^-2]` where `c, k1, k2` are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has no unique solution. We can define exact solutions satisfier to `ϕ1[0] ==0, ϕ2'[L] == 0` in a form

```
ϕ1[s_] = 2 JacobiAmplitude[k1 Sqrt[F - T] s, k1^-2];
ϕ2[s_] = Pi + 2 JacobiAmplitude[(s k2 Sqrt[T] + c), k2^-2];
```

where `c, k1, k2` are arbitrary constants. Note that `ϕ1[0] =0`. Using boundary condition `ϕ2'[L] == 0` we have

```
 ϕ2'[L]=2 k2 Sqrt[T] JacobiDN[c + k2 L Sqrt[T], 1/k2^2]
 Reduce[JacobiDN[x, 1/k2^2] == 0, x]
```

Solution depends on 2 integer constant

```
 (C[1] | C[2]) \[Element]Integers && (x == 
4 I C[2] EllipticK[1 - 1/k2^2] + 2 C[1] EllipticK[1/k2^2] - 
 InverseJacobiDN[0, 1/k^2] || 
 x == 4 I C[2] EllipticK[1 - 1/k2^2] + 2 C[1] EllipticK[1/k2^2] + 
     InverseJacobiDN[0, 1/k2^2])
```

Therefore

```
c[n1_, n2_, n3_, k_, h_] := 
  4 I n1 EllipticK[1 - 1/k^2] + 
   2 n2 EllipticK[1/k^2] + (-1)^n3 InverseJacobiDN[0, 1/k^2] - h;
```

where `k=k2, h=k L Sqrt[T]`, `n1,n2` are integers, and $n3=1,2$.

These multiple solutions `ϕ2[s]` are very sensitive to the value $l$ and `DD`. For example, for `sL = 10; sm = sL*(1/10); dd = 1/10; mu = 1;` we have from bbgodfrey code

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{\[Phi]1''[s] - g[s]*Sin[\[Phi]1[s]] == 0, 
    g'[s] == 0, 
    d'[s] == Cos[\[Phi]1[s]], \[Phi]1[0] == 0, \[Phi]1[sm] == 
     ArcTan[1/mu], d[0] == 0, d[sm] == dd}, {\[Phi]1[s], \[Phi]1'[s], 
    g[s]}, {s, 0, sL}, InitialSeeding -> {g[sm] == -1/2}];
```

Hence `T-F` evaluated as

```
sol1[[3]] /. s -> sm

(*Out[]= -13.4709*)
```

From our code we have same result

```
(T - F) /. {T -> 50.74724219864135`, F -> 64.21815429080017`}

(*Out[]= -13.4709*)
```

But for `T` we have from bbgodfrey code

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{\[Phi]2''[s] - t[s]*Sin[\[Phi]2[s]] == 0, 
    t'[s] == 0, \[Phi]2'[sm] == (sol1[[2]] /. s -> sm), \[Phi]2[sm] ==
      ArcTan[1/mu], \[Phi]2'[sL] == 0}, {\[Phi]2[s], \[Phi]2'[s], 
    t[sm]}, {s, 0, sL}, InitialSeeding -> t[sL] == 10, 
   MaxSteps -> 10^6];
sol2[[3]]
(*51.3391*)
```

If we define function

```
fin[s_] := 
  Piecewise[{{sol1[[1]], 0 <= s < sm}, {sol2[[1]], sm <= s <= sL}}];
```

then we can visualize `sol1, sol2` as follows

```
{Plot[{sol1[[1]], sol2[[1]]}, {s, 0, sL}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\[Phi]1[s]", "\[Phi]2[s]"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[fin[s]], {s, 0, sL}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note that our solution with `{T -> 50.74724219864135, F -> 64.21815429080017}` looks quite different
[image: Figure 2]