# Understanding the calculation of the periodic function $f(x)=x-x^3, \quad -1<x<1$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, reference-request, fourier-analysis

It is given the following periodic function
$$f(x)=x-x^3, \quad -1<x<1$$
This is an odd function, so the coefficients $a_n,a_0$ of the Fourier Series are zero.

Usually, I face function with two branches so I tried to code it on Mathematica as follows:

```
f[x_] := Which[-1 < x <= 0, x - x^3, 0 < x < 1, x - x^3]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

***Edited***

```
a[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
a[0] := (1/L)*Integrate[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
b[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
F[x_, Nmax_] := 
 a[0] + Sum[a[n]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, N}]
p[Nmax_, a_] := 
 Plot[Evaluate[F[x, Nmax]], {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 200]
L = 2;
f[x_] := If[x > 0, x - x^3, x - x^3];
a[n]
a[0]
b[n]
Simplify[b[n], n \[Element] Integers]

Integrate[f[x]^2, {x, -L, L}]
(a[0]^2)/2 + Sum[(a[n]^2 + b[n]^2), {n, 1, Infinity}] <= 
 Integrate[f[x]^2, {x, -L, L}]
```

Is my consideration correct? I can realize that the two plots are the same and for this reason seems weird.
[image]

Comment: `f[x_] := Which[-1 < x <= 0, x - x^3, 0 < x < 1, x - x^3]` is equivalent to: `f[x_]:= x - x^3`

Comment: You should not use `N` as variable.  Also, please clarify what is your question more clearly. Are you asking if your Fourier series manual calculations correct or not?

Comment: @Nasser I used it as my professor showed us. I did not know that is wrong. Yes, I am asking if the calculation is correct. Here, I can realize that we have a continuous function. So there is no Gibbs Phenomenon.

Comment: @Nasser  is this the reason that the plots are identical?

Comment: For reference: [Fourier series in Mathematica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF1tOcEVGyU) video tutorial.

Comment: Expanding on what @Nasser told you. Some capital letters in `Mathematica` are built-in symbols. If you don't remember which ones, don't use any. For example you could have written `NN` instead of `N` as your variable. You can test. Try `?? N` and see what you get. To avoid this test here's a simple mnemonic. Don't use `ONE DICK`; shameless advertising see [**`here`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266402/is-k-is-a-function/266404#266404) and the [**`linked one`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117877/capital-letters-that-are-built-in-symbols)

Comment: @Syed thanks that was really helpful

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the reasoning behind the vote? It would be more beneficial to the author of the O.P. Also, I don't see any reason for a downvote. It's a clear question and some effort was made. Code was provided. The post is nicely formatted. And I can go on...

Comment: @bmf Understood I have to be more careful with the variables. I will fix it. Is there any answer for my question why the two plots are identical?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos sorry. I did not have the time to check.

Comment: @bmf I have changed the variables as you said to me. If you have the time to check it  I would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos I was about to explain the same thing that Nasser explained to you. They are not identical for low values, but they are really close

Comment: @bmf Thank you for your helpful explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this the reason that the plots are identical?

They are not identical. But the approximation is very good. Even for 2 terms, you get very good approximation. You can see this as below

```
L = 2; (*period*)
f[x_] := x - x^3;
a[n_, x_] = (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
a[n_ /; n == 0, x_] = (1/L)*Integrate[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
b[n_, x_] = (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice also since odd function, only $b_n$ survives.

```
fFourierApprox[x_, nTerms_] := 
  a[0, x] + Sum[a[n, x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n, x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1,  nTerms}];
```

Let compare $f(x)$ with its Fourier series, using one term only

```
Plot[{f[x], fFourierApprox[x, 1]}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f(x)", "approx"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using 2 terms now

```
Plot[{f[x], fFourierApprox[x, 2]}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f(x)", "approx"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With 3 terms you can hardly see the difference

```
Plot[{f[x],fFourierApprox[x,3]},{x,-L/2,L/2},PlotLegends->{"f(x)","approx"},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You original function is continuous, so as typical in Fourier series, few terms are needed to give very accurate approximation. (There are more Fourier series animations showing this point all done using Mathematica I saw at this [page](https://12000.org/my_notes/fourier_series_animations/index.htm))

ps. If you extend the range to the full -L..L, this is the result using only one term in F.S.

```
Plot[{f[x], fFourierApprox[x, 1]}, {x, -L, L}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f(x)", "approx"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh thank you. I was so confused. I have to compare them